# Little problem with slash commands (discord.js v13)

Tags: discord.js

Slash commands work well, no hassle, set with simple code: `bot.commands.set(command.name, command)`
But I noticed that they are set only when the bot is running and it is added to the Discord server. If the bot is already on the Discord server, and a new command appeared later, then command does not appear in the list. I fix this by a second invitation, but commands in the list start to double, as if they were cloning yourself. Can this be fixable?

Comment: AFAIK you can't actually remove slash commands, but they may disappear after some time. If it's really an issue you could delete and recreate the application via the Developer Portal.

Comment: @Shay You definitely can remove slash commands, your answer was extremely misleading. You can remove slash commands by using `bot.application.commands.delete`(global commands) where bot is the DiscordClient or guild commands: `guild.commands.delete`, where guild is the targeted Guild. These are both functions, and require a command id. You can fetch command ids using: `bot.commands.fetch().then(c=> console.log(c))`(global cmds), `guild.commands.fetch().then(c=>console.log(c))`(server commands).

Comment: @Jeffplays2005 that can be posted as answer since it answers the question - but it may need to go more in detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove slash commands either from global commands or server commands. Fetching the commands then logging or using another method to show you the command id will allow you to use the delete method.

You can remove slash commands by using `bot.application.commands.delete('id here')`. (global commands) where bot is the DiscordClient or guild commands: `guild.commands.delete('id here')`, where guild is the targeted Guild.

These are both functions, and require a command id. You can fetch command ids using: `bot.application.commands.fetch().then(c=> console.log(c))`(global cmds), `guild.commands.fetch().then(c=>console.log(c))`(server commands)

Comment: `TypeError: bot.commands.fetch is not a function`

Comment: Omg, I forgot, its bot.application.commands.fetch, sorry for the misleading answer, I'll edit it now!

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is working, thank you very much.